# Does phimosis have a causal relationship with overactive bladder?

Tags: penis, bladder-infection

There is some relation between the frenulum and urinary sphincter muscles; these two help each other to facilitate fluid movement through the urethral passage. A shorter frenulum can cause [phimosis](https://urology.ucsf.edu/patient-care/children/phimosis) due to which an unexposed glans may become very sensitive to touch, and can oversensitive glans cause bladder to be sensitive too?

Academic research material on this topic isn't visible. Feel free to share any useful articles.

There may be some articles like [this](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8065077/) one, but more clarity is needed.

Comment: The glans is generally sensitive to touch with a circumcised foreskin or uncircumcised. (https://doi.org/10.1002/sm2.67)

Comment: Circumcised or not, I don't follow your reasoning. Why would a sensitized glans have an effect on the bladder?

Answer (score 4):

There is a relationship between [phimosis and urinary tract infections](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/000992289303200301), which can cause urinary incontinence, increased urinary frequency and a recurrent "urge to pee"- nothing to do with sensitivity though.

It should be noted, as I referenced a study on male infants, that phimosis is a normal condition up until age 5-7 years, when the foreskin naturally starts to retract fully.

I'd say "citation needed" for the phimosis and sensitivity though.

1. Wiswell TE, Hachey WE. Urinary Tract Infections and the Uncircumcised State: An Update. Clinical Pediatrics. 1993;32(3):130-134. doi:10.1177/000992289303200301